# Evaluating a contour integral (don't understand my error)

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to evaluate the integral

$$ I = \int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{(z-a)(z-b)} dz$$

over the the circle of radius $r$ at the origin (assume that $|a| < r < |b|)$. Please note I haven't yet reached Cauchy's theorem in my book.

Then we have

$$ I = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{ire^{it}}{(re^{it}-a)(re^{it}-b)} dt$$

And then we note that:

$$
\frac{1}{(re^{it}-a)(re^{it}-b)} = \frac{a-b}{(a-b)(re^{it}-a)(re^{it}-b)} = \frac{(re^{it}-b)-(re^{it}-a)}{(a-b)(re^{it}-a)(re^{it}-b)} = \\
\frac{1}{(a-b)(re^{it}-a)} + \frac{1}{(b-a)(re^{it}-b)}
$$

So then we have

$$ I = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{ire^{it}}{(a-b)(re^{it}-a)} dt + \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{ire^{it}}{(b-a)(re^{it}-b)} dt $$

When I try to make a substitution $u = r e^{it} - a$ in the first integral (and similarly for the second integral) I have an answer like

$$ I = \frac{ \log(r e^{it} - a) ]_0^{2\pi}}{a-b} + \frac{ \log(r e^{it} - b) ]_0^{2\pi}}{b-a}$$

which is $0$ and I do not think this is the correct answer; however I'm not sure what I did incorrectly along the way.

Comment: The short answer is that $\log$ cannot be (continuously) defined on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$. You need a branch-cut connecting $0$ to $\infty$, then you can define branches of the logarithm on the complement of the branch cut. While $r^{i2\pi} - a = re^{i0} - a$, if you define a branch of the logarithm on a domain containing $re^{it} - a$ for $0 < t <  2\pi$, then $$\lim_{t \to 2\pi^-} \log \bigl(re^{it} - a\bigr) - \lim_{t \to 0^+} \log \bigl( re^{it} -a \bigr) = 2 \pi i.$$

Answer (score -1):

**Added later:** I seem to be getting downvoted because I did not answer the specific question asked. So be it. I think the below will be of help to others who have this question.

---

I would do this using series expansions: Write

$$\frac{1}{(z-a)(z-b)} = \frac{A}{z-a}
+ \frac{B}{z-b},$$

where the constants $A,B$ are easy enough to find. So we're left trying to figure out the integrals $\int_\gamma dz/(z-a),\int_\gamma dz/(z-b).$ The first integral equals

$$\tag 1\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{ire^{it}}{re^{it}-a}\,dt = i\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{1-(a/r)e^{-it}}\,dt$$ $$ = i\int_0^{2\pi}\left (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(a/r)^ne^{-int}\right )\,dt = i\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_0^{2\pi}(a/r)^ne^{-int}\,dt.$$

The only summand on the right that is nonzero is the $n=0$ term, so we see $(1)$ equals $2\pi i.$

The second integral can be handled similarly.